# Running a bash script with root access in ubuntu

Tags: bash, root

I am trying to write a bash script which will switch to user and execute a program. But I am not able to execute the program after switching. This is the script I wrote

```
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo su
    /opt/genymobile/genymotion/genymotion
    echo "hi"
```

Comment: What about about `sudo my_script.sh` ?

Answer (score 2):

`sudo su` gives you a new shell. while this shell is running other command are not executed. try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su -c '/opt/genymobile/genymotion/genymotion ; echo "hi"'
```

Answer (score 2):

If your script does something that requires root access the system will already check for the permissions and block access.

You can just check for the current user and abort:

```
if [ ! `id -u` = 0 ]; then 
 echo "ERROR: This script must be run as the root user"
fi
```